# MVC Two Class Within One Model Conflict while Saving data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

My Code is as shown in below

**MODEL**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace MyProject.Models
{
    [Table("UserMaster")]
    public partial class UserMaster
    {
     [Key]
     public int UserID { get; set; }
    [System.Web.Mvc.Remote("doesAlreadyExist", "User", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "User Number already exists. Please enter a different Number.")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Personal No")]
    [Display(Name = "User No")]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string User No{ get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Password")]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Password doesn't match.")]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
    public string CPassword { get; set; }
}


public class UserChangePassMV
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Old Password")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string OldPassword { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "New Password")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string NewPassword { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Compare("NewPassword",ErrorMessage="Password Doesnt Match in User Change Password.")]

        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
public class ChangeAvatar
    {
        public byte[] Photo { get; set; }

        public string ImgSrc { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**CONROLLER**

```
  [OutputCache(Duration = 10, VaryByParam = "none", Location = OutputCacheLocation.Client, NoStore = true)]
        public ActionResult ChangeAvatar()
        {
            ChangeAvatar avatar = new Models.ChangeAvatar();
            int uid = Convert.ToInt32(Session.GetDataFromSession<CommonUserSession>("CommonUserSession").UserID);
            avatar.Photo = db.UserMasters.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserID == uid).Photo;

            if (avatar.Photo != null)
            {
                string imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(avatar.Photo);
                avatar.ImgSrc = string.Format("data:image/jpeg;base64,{0}", imageBase64);
            }
            return View("ChangeAvatar", "_Layout", avatar);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ChangeAvatar(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            if (file == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Select image to upload");
            }

            int uid = Convert.ToInt32(Session.GetDataFromSession<CommonUserSession>("CommonUserSession").UserID);
            UserMaster Mem = db.UserMasters.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserID == uid);
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/ProfileImg"), uid.ToString() + ".jpg");
                    // file is uploaded
                    file.SaveAs(path);

                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        file.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
                        byte[] array = ms.GetBuffer();
                        Mem.Photo = array;
                    }
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("ChangeAvatar");
                }
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
            {
                var errorMessages = ex.EntityValidationErrors
                        .SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors)
                        .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage);


                var fullErrorMessage = string.Join("; ", errorMessages);

                var exceptionMessage = string.Concat(ex.Message, " The validation errors are: ", fullErrorMessage);
                HtmlHelperExtensions.LogError(ex);
                throw new DbEntityValidationException(exceptionMessage, ex.EntityValidationErrors);

            }
            catch (RetryLimitExceededException /* dex */)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
            }

            ChangeAvatar avatar = new Models.ChangeAvatar();
            avatar.Photo = db.UserMasters.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserID == uid).Photo;

            if (avatar.Photo != null)
            {
                string imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(avatar.Photo);
                avatar.ImgSrc = string.Format("data:image/jpeg;base64,{0}", imageBase64);
            }
            return View(avatar);
        }
```

**VIEW**

```
@model MyProject.Models.ChangeAvatar
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Change Avatar";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<!-- BEGIN PAGE BAR -->
@section PageBreadcrumb{
    <ul class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="~/Home/Index"><i class="icon-home2 position-left"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
        <li class="active">Change Avatar</li>
    </ul>
}
<!-- END PAGE BAR -->
<div class="clearfix"></div>
@section PageJS{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/assets/js/plugins/uploaders/fileinput.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/assets/js/pages/uploader_bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if ('@ViewBag.Status' != "") {
            var notice = new PNotify({
                title: '@ViewBag.Status',
                text: '@ViewBag.Msg',
                addclass: 'bg-@ViewBag.Type' //primary,info,danger,success,warning
            }).get().click(function () {
                notice.remove(); //Click to remove
            });

        }
    </script>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("ChangeAvatar", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <div class="panel panel-flat">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h5 class="panel-title text-primary">Change Avatar</h5>
            <div class="heading-elements">
                <ul class="icons-list">
                    <li><a data-action="collapse"></a></li>
                    @*<li><a data-action="reload"></a></li>
                        <li><a data-action="close"></a></li>*@
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="col-md-12">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label text-semibold">Avatar:</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <input type="file" name="file" class="file-input-custom" data-show-caption="true" data-show-upload="true" accept="image/*">
                        <span class="help-block">Show only image files for selection &amp; preview.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="text-right">
                        <p>
                            <div class="text-right">
                                @*<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Change <i class="icon-arrow-right14 position-right"></i></button>*@
                            </div>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Now while I am trying to save the data in Change Avatar it shows error of first model for

```
Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details. The validation errors are: Password doesn't match.
```

If i remove Compare part than it works, but i need that compare to confirm password

is this possible to work with two class like this?

Help me out I am stuck here.

Comment: Seems that validation check using `ModelState.IsValid` triggered `DbEntityValidationException` there, since usage of `UserMaster` viewmodel is suspicious due to validation constraint apply: `UserMaster Mem = db.UserMasters.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserID == uid);`

Comment: I have use 

`@model MyProject.Models.ChangeAvatar`
in view

Comment: Could you paste your view code as well? Do you have your client side validation enabled?

Comment: @IvanGritsenko yes it is enabled because my other validation working well , just this two models are conflicted , also while i am using change password i am facing same problem.

Comment: I think you are getting the error when `db.SaveChanges();` executes. It triggers EF validation. If so I may advise you to use additional ViewModel class which will contain `Compare`.

Comment: yes , does it have any solution?

Comment: I suggest you using another viewmodel without validation constraint which reflects `UserMaster` viewmodel before executing `db.SaveChanges()`. Viewmodels with validation attributes/constraints should only used to interact with view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `UserMaster` class has a `CPassword` property which will be set to null when you do `db.UserMasters.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserID == uid)`. You update `Photo` field and save the entity. `db.SaveChanges();` triggers validation on your entity which is comparing password field values producing the exception. Both MVC and EF use data annotation attributes for validation. EF reads an attribute designed for presentation layer.

Think why do you need a `CPassword` field in your model class? It is not stored in the database. It is needed only to capture user input. Usually this is so-called **viewModel** class responsibility. In order to resolve the issue split `UserMaster` into separate classes.

```
public partial class UserMaster
{
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string UserNo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class UserMasterViewModel
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [System.Web.Mvc.Remote("doesAlreadyExist", "User", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "User Number already exists. Please enter a different Number.")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Personal No")]
    [Display(Name = "User No")]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string UserNo{ get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Password")]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Password doesn't match.")]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
    public string CPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Use `UserMasterViewModel` as a @model of your views. Perform dbModel <=> viewModel mappings in you controller methods.

Comment: is there any easy way of Mapping coz I have more than 50 fields in main model .

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1043977/Mapping-ViewModel-to-Model-in-ASP-NET-MVC-using-Im

i am taking ref. from above link.

Comment: @Ravi Mehta Well, there is indeed. [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) was designed specifically for such purposes.